# Can SelectSingleNode be used in a loop instead of Select?

Tags: c#, xpath

Is there a way to use SelectSingleNode in a loop, or recursively,  to get the same
 set of nodes that the Select method returns? The reason I don't want to use 
Select is because while it is executing I cannot display progress messages to
 the user. Furthermore, if it takes a long time then the application may appear to 
have stopped responding and the user may think it is hung up.  If I can use 
SelectSingleNode repeatedly, then I can show progress and keep the application
 resposive. I need this to work with any XPath expression the user might input.
 After the first SelectSingleNode, I think the xpath expression would have to be 
changed so the start point is the current context  and I cannot figure that out.

```
        string localXPathExpr = "//b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')]";

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
        settings.XmlResolver = null;
        XmlReader reader = null;
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr=null;
        XPathNavigator nav = null;
        XPathNodeIterator xNode = null;            

            reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlfile, settings); 
            nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
            //if xpath has prefix, extract it and add to namespacemanager
            string prefix = Form1.NSPrefix(localXPathExpr);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) == false)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Form1.NSUri) == false) 
                {
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace(prefix, Form1.NSUri);
                }
                else
                {
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace(prefix, rootNodeNamespace);
                }
            }                 XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
            nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

           // xNode = nav.Select(localXPathExpr, nsmgr); 
            XPathNavigator single = nav.SelectSingleNode(localXPathExpr, nsmgr);
           //to get the next book, I think the xpath expression would have to be      changed so the start point is the current context of single
          // I tried the current context operator  "./b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')]" and also tried
          // "/b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')]" but they both return null.
            XPathNavigator next = single.SelectSingleNode(localXPathExpr, nsmgr);
```

Input source:

```
<bookstore xmlns="http://www.mybookstore.com/books">
    <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1847-11-17" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
        <title>The Confidence Man</title>
        <author>
            <first-name>Herman</first-name>
            <last-name>Melville</last-name>
        </author>
        <price>11.99</price>
    </book>
 <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1841-09-11" ISBN="0-201-76361-2">
        <title>Moby Dick</title>
        <author>
            <first-name>Herman</first-name>
            <last-name>Melville</last-name>
        </author>
        <price>11.99</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: You wrote *" I don't want to use Select is because while it is executing I cannot display progress messages to the user. Furthermore, if it takes a long time then the application may appear to have stopped responding"* I don't understand how this is a concern... Unless you are doing something wrong, an XPath expression evaluation should not take a lot of time.

Comment: it can if user's machine has 8 Gb of ram and they doan xpath query on an xml that has several million elements.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for analysis and recommendations.

Comment: You wrote *"xml [...] has several million elements"*. Perhaps you should use a streaming solution, like SAX or some XSLT processor with that feature.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Yes, but ...

**There are several issues that have to be addressed**:

.1. **If the XML file is huge, I suspect that the big processing time is spent not in evaluating the XPath expression itself**, but in parsing the XML file.

.2. **Always try to avoid using the `//` abbreviation**, as it most often causes very slow evaluation. If you know the structure of the XML document and `b:book` only appears at certain locations, it would be much more efficient to use (for example):

```
/*/b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')]
```

than

```
//b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')]
```

.3. **Only in case you cannot do .2. above, then you can implement the following**:

Call in a loop `SelectSingleNode()` for the following expressions (the index should be the loop counter):

```
   (//b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')])[1]

   (//b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')])[2]

   (//b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')])[3]

   (//b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')])[4]
```

.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .

Assuming that the optimizer is good and stops evaluating the complete expression when it has found the wanted occurence, the evaluation of the first expressions will be much faster than evaluating the complete expression `//b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')]`.

Of course, the time for selecting the last nodes will be still very big, so you may employ a mixed strategy: select the first N (say 100) nodes one by one, and then evaluate the complete expression `//b:book[contains(b:author,'Melville')]`.

Comment: Thanks. that should work. I was trying to find a way to get the first node, then get the next one by starting at the current context and so on. That way I could show the first N nodes to the user and then resume the query without having to start from the root. Is that not possible?

Comment: Yes: `lastNodeFound//descendents::expression | lastNodeFound//following::expression`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any clear solution using `SelectSingleNode`.

I'd suggest you to use the full `Select` and a `BackgroundWorker` thread to make your form responsive during the selection (of course this prevent the possibility to show the progress of selection).

BTW, I suppose that the slowness of you xpath query is due to the `contains` part.
So, as a work around, you could do something like this:

1. Simplify your xpath removing the `contains` (your select should be significantly faster)
2. Perform the selection and keep the list of nodes
3. Iterate the nodes performing the `contains` previously removed. In this loop you can show a progress bar...

Comment: The Select method is a black box. I could use a background worker with a timer, yes. But there is still no way to directly monitor what is going on until the Select method completes. After that one may iterate through the nodelist, which is what have been doing -that takes virtually no time at all so is not an issue.

Comment: @Bill: It takes no time because is already in memory. Unfortunately I don't see any solution to your problem... if you have a huge xml you can't pretend to be fast, for such kind of selections a DB would fit much better...

Comment: OK. then the real performance issue is the   XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should investigate what is taking up most of the time. It's quite possible that parsing the `XPathDocument` will be the most time consuming part. You can provide feedback during the parsing process by extending the `XmlTextReader` class. A very simple example:

```
public class MyXmlReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public MyXmlReader(string filename)
        : base(filename)
    {
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading line {0}.", this.LineNumber);
        return base.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't a way to do what you suggest in the default .NET libraries, in [XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp/com/) the XPath implementation has the method [Evaluate](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/doc/2.0/M_XQSharp_XPath_Evaluate.htm) which will perform a lazy evaluation of the expression, which will mean you can report the progress as you evaluate each item rather than evaluating them all upfront.

(Disclaimer: I'm on the XQSharp development team)